# rake spec gives me error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

HI guys,

I am not good with gem management and having problem getting my RSpec to work properly. In my

```
gem list
```

I have these

```
rspec (2.1.0)
rspec-core (2.1.0)
rspec-expectations (2.1.0)
rspec-mocks (2.1.0)
rspec-rails (2.1.0)
```

And when I run `rake spec` I get these

```
/Users/denniss/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby -S bundle exec rspec "./spec/controllers

/admin/categories_controller_spec.rb" "./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb"
bundler: command not found: rspec
Install missing gem binaries with `bundle install`
rake aborted!
ruby -S bundle exec rspec "./spec/controllers/admin/categories_controller_spec.rb" "./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb" failed
```

I tried running bundle install for missing gem binaries and I got this

```
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /Users/denniss/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02
```

I don't know what is happening and I have tried debugging and googling without no progress. So please help me if you know how to get these fixed.

If I am doing something wrong please let me know as well

Comment: Try running `bundle exec rake spec` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Theo: I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you may need to add the gem executable directory to your load path. To get the executable directory, run `gem environment` in terminal and look for a line that says:

```
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /gem/path/bin
```

Copy the path and enter it in the following terminal command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/gem/path/bin
```

Edit:

I noticed you're using bundler. The gems shown in `gem list` is completely separate from the gems that bundler is using. Does `bundle show` also list these gems? If not, you will need to add them to your Gemfile.

Comment: bundle show gives me this  * rspec (2.1.0)
  * rspec-core (2.1.0)
  * rspec-expectations (2.1.0)
  * rspec-mocks (2.1.0)
  * rspec-rails (2.1.0)

Comment: I suspect a broken installation of RVM, since all executables installed by bundler should be available in the path, because Bundler knows RVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try follow command in your project:
$ rails generate rspec:install

It creates .rspec, spec, spec/spec_helper...afterwards the rake spec command should work